# Firebase Database Web

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I am having issues trying to figure this out. I come from a SQL background and am new to Firebase database. I am building a website that sells individual videos online. What I am trying to do seems simple but I can't for the life of me get it to work.

I want to show a page listing only the videos a user has purchased and not the entire list of videos available. Obviously, because I only want the user to access what they have purchased. Currently, I can display the list of all videos and category heading for each category. I can't figure out how to restrict this list to display only the videos the user has purchased.

Here is my Database Structure

[image: Firebase].

As you can see I have videos and their info in a "videos" collection and users in a "users" collection. Under each user is a "pvideos" collection that shows the id of each video the user has purchased.

Any ideas on how I might write this to restrict the list to match only the videos the user has purchased?

Included is the code that displays the category heading and videos (currently) for all available videos regardless of purchase status.

```
var series = db.child('videos').orderByKey();
                                series.once('value')
                                    .then(function (snapshot) {
                                        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

                                var videoseries = childSnapshot.key;
                                console.log(videoseries);
                                var seriesheading = document.createElement('h3');
                                seriesheading.textContent = videoseries;
                                seriesheading.setAttribute('class', 'bg-color-2');
                                document.getElementById("container").appendChild(seriesheading);

                                var videodata = db.child('videos/' + videoseries).orderByKey();
                                videodata.once('value')
                                    .then(function (snapshot) {
                                        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

                                            var videoid = childSnapshot.key;
                                            var vimeo = childSnapshot.child('vimeo').val();
                                            var videoname = childSnapshot.child('name').val();
                                            var videolength = childSnapshot.child('length').val();
                                            var videodesc = childSnapshot.child('desc').val();

                                            console.log(videoid);
                                            console.log(vimeo);
                                            console.log(videoname);
                                            console.log(videolength);
                                            console.log(videodesc);                                             
                                            var videolisting = document.createElement('div');
                                            videolisting.setAttribute('class', 'row');
                                            videolisting.innerHTML = "<div class='col-md-6'><div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9'><iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + vimeo + "' frameborder='0' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div><div class='col-md-6'><h3>" + videoname + "</h3><small>" + videolength + "</small><p>" + videodesc + "</p></div><hr>";
                                            document.getElementById("container").appendChild(videolisting);
                                        });
                                    });
                            });
                    });
```

Comment: Anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you restructure your database to look like this

```
users
    -cvbnm876567890 
        - emeil : 'email@email.com'
        - name : 'user name'
        - pvideos
            -fghjk098u6sgs78d80s
                -desc : 'description'
                -vimeo : 'vimeo_link'
                -name : 'name'
                -length : 'length'
                -category : 'category'
            -oiu345ytrdfghj67890
                -desc : 'description'
                -vimeo : 'vimeo_link'
                -name : 'name'
                -length : 'length'
                -category : 'category'

videos 
 - videokey1
   - category : "Walking Series"
 - videokey2
   - category : "Running Series"

videos_categories 
 - Walking Series
 - Running Series
```

You can use `db.child('videos').orderByChild('category').equalTo('Walking Series')` to get videos in a single category or series. You can modify your query to look like this

```
var series = db.child('videos_categories').orderByKey();
series.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var videoseries = childSnapshot.key;
        console.log(videoseries);
        var category_wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        category_wrapper.setAttribute('class', 'row');
        category_wrapper.setAttribute('id', videoseries);
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(category_wrapper);
        var seriesheading = document.createElement('h3');
        seriesheading.textContent = videoseries;
        seriesheading.setAttribute('class', 'bg-color-2');
        document.getElementById(videoseries).appendChild(seriesheading);
    });
}).then(() => {
    var videodata = db.child('videos').orderByChild('category');
    videodata.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var videoid = childSnapshot.key;
            var vimeo = childSnapshot.child('vimeo').val();
            var videoname = childSnapshot.child('name').val();
            var videolength = childSnapshot.child('length').val();
            var videodesc = childSnapshot.child('desc').val();
            var video_category = childSnapshot.child('category').val();
            console.log(videoid);
            console.log(vimeo);
            console.log(videoname);
            console.log(videolength);
            console.log(videodesc);
            var videolisting = document.createElement('div');
            videolisting.setAttribute('class', 'row');
            videolisting.innerHTML = "<div class='col-md-6'><div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9'><iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + vimeo + "' frameborder='0' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div><div class='col-md-6'><h3>" + videoname + "</h3><small>" + videolength + "</small><p>" + videodesc + "</p></div><hr>";
            document.getElementById(video_category).appendChild(videolisting);
        });
    });
});
```

Denormalizing your data is important in firebase. So you save the data the way you want it to appear in your view.

You dont need to add every information regarding that video to the user node. Just the details you would need when listing the videos then fetch from the videos node when getting one video

I hope this helps. If you find a better way please share.

Answer (score 0):

@hazelcodes, thank you for the help. Though since it was three weeks ago that I asked for the help, I had already figured it out. Nevertheless, I am grateful. In regards to your statement

> "You don't need to add every information regarding that
>   video to the user node. Just the details you would need when listing
>   the videos then fetch from the videos node when getting one video."

this is actually what I ended up doing. I completely pulled out 'pvideos' from the user information and made it its own object. I now have three separate object nodes. One for 'users', one for 'videos' and a third for 'pvideos' (videos each user has purchased) like so.

```
users
  abcde (uid)
  name: Joe
  email: joe@joe.com
  ...

videos
  1234 (videoid)
    name: An Awesome Video
    ...

  5678 (videoid)
    name: Another Rad Video
    ...

pvideos
  abcde (uid)
    5678 (videoid)
      orderid: 99999999
```

In doing it this way, I am able to check which videos the user has purchased from 'pvideos' and show only the information for the matching videoid in 'videos'.

As the user purchases a new video, it is then added as a child of 'pvideos/uid'. If a users uid does not exist as a child of 'pvideos' it is because they have not purchased any videos. Once they purchase their first video the appropriate children are created.

As for the category, I decided that since currently, all videos belong to a single category, I would simply not use the category for now. That was a question I was going to have however when I got to the point of needing additional categories. After your answer here regarding this, I now know how to implement this when the time comes.

Comment: Cool... Good to know my answer was helpful in some way.